# Удаление файлов в Java после чтения

Tags: java, io

Как мне удалити оба файла? У меня 2.txt удаляеться а 1.txt нет

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("D:\\project\\1.txt");
   list.add("D:\\project\\2.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\project\\compressed.zip");
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        File fileToZip = new File(list.get(i).toString());
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName());
        zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        fileToZip.delete();
    }
        zipOut.close();
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++)
        new File(list.get(i).toString()).delete();

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не закрыли FileInputStream. Вы его открываете в цикле:

```
fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
```

А закрываете уже вне цикла:

```
fis.close();
```

Таким образом закрывается только последний пройденный в цикле, а все что было до этого, так и висит.

Comment: спасибо)
а в java можно добавлять файлы в текущий архив?